# yii2 display error msg

Tags: php, html, css, forms, yii2

displaying msg on above the line, how to display error msg below line. I have added below view page. any suggestions.

[image]

below is view page

```
<div class="ibox-content bwform clearfix" id="bwcart">
<h2><b>Profile</b><div id="loader"></div></h2>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        ['action' =>'',
        'options' => ['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'profile-form','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}<div class=\"col-md-12\">{input}\n{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-12 control-label p-l-0'],
        ],
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'enableClientValidation' => true,'validateOnSubmit'=>true]); ?>

        <div class="box-2">
        <div class="input input--hoshi <?=$prefilled ?>">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'firstname')->textInput(array('placeholder' => '','class'=>'input__field input__field--hoshi'))->label(false); ?>

            <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-3" for="first_name">             
                <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--hoshi">First Name</span>
            </label>              
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-2">
            <div class="input input--hoshi <?=$prefilled ?>">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname')->textInput(array('placeholder' => '','class'=>'input__field input__field--hoshi'))->label(false); ?>
                <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-3" for="first_name">             
                <span class="input__label-content input__label-content--hoshi">Last Name</span>
            </label> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `template` is a template for rendered HTML, and adding new line in HTML will have no effect how it is displayed in browser. You may use `<br>` instead of `\n`, but it is better to build layout using separate divs for these elements.

Comment: i suspect it is a css issue as the configurations for the error string is correctly placed , and if i copy your code at my end it shows the error below the input not above

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        ['action' =>'',
        'options' => ['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'profile-form','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
         //modify this
            'template' => "{label}<div class='col-md-12'>{input}</div><div class='col-md-12 '>{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-12 control-label p-l-0'],
        ],
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'enableClientValidation' => true,'validateOnSubmit'=>true]); ?>
```

So your error tag is positioned
 under your input tag.

Comment: it's the same result?I mean the div with the error inside where is positioned?

Answer (score 0):

Your `error` attribute should not be in your `col-md-12` class `div`.

So it should be like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(
        ['action' =>'',
        'options' => ['method'=>'post','class'=>'form-horizontal','id'=>'profile-form','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'],
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}<div class=\"col-md-12\">{input}</div>{error}",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-12 control-label p-l-0'],
        ],
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,'enableClientValidation' => true,'validateOnSubmit'=>true]); ?>
```